# Master dataset of all recent password and hash leaks?

Tags: passwords

There has been a recent spate of password and hash leaks from LinkedIn, Ashley Madison etc. Is there a dataset available online which is a unification of all such leaks (major and minor) aggregated together by frequency and source?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here - they tend to go out of date too quickly. You might have some luck with sites like haveibeenpwned, depending on what data you're looking for, but be aware that they only report leaks where they have been able to get a copy of the data. That's some subset of all leaks which are reported, which is a subset of all actual leaks. We don't know how much of a subset each category is...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Matthew in the comment, the site https://haveibeenpwned.com/ is probably your best bet.  It is run by Troy Hunt (a respected security researcher) who collects the various leaks and data sets, and lets you search to see if your account has been part of one of the leaks.  He *does not* make available the raw dumps.  He does, however, provide an API if you want to search his data set, suitably cleaned up, to be useful for researchers, without propagating exploitable data.

API page here:

https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2